# Plotting coordinates for sequence alignment

Tags: r

I would like to reproduce this figure from a recent publication in R, but I am unsure how.

[image]

The plot's idea is simple. At the top is a representation of a full length virus sequence and each line underneath it depicts a sequenced isolate.

For each sequence, there are two pieces of information:

1. Where the sequence starts, ends, deleted, etc
   For instance: sequence 1, starts at position 1 and ends at position 9000
   But sequence 2, starts at position 1, ends at 2000, in the middle everything is deleted and then starts again at 8000-9000
2. Color-coded based on whether it is deleted, full-length, etc

Initially I thought I could use a bar graph, like this one I drew in Illustrator, where the x would be essentially each sequence line and the y would be the coordinates of where it maps. But I am not sure if this will allow me to designate "gaps", as seen in sequence 3 in my illustrator picture.

[image]

The data itself is organized as such:

```
Sequence name    Mapped Start   Mapped End
1                1              9000
2                4000           9000 
3                1              2000
3                7000           9000
```

The data set only includes the mapped start and end positions, not the deleted positions.

Would appreciate hearing your input!

Thanks

Comment: If the figure 1 you provided is done in R, there is no doubt it can't be reproduced. I can think of few way of reproducing it, but without having a look at any data (even sample of it), it can be very difficult for anyone to provide you a good solution. So I suggest you include sample data in the question.

Comment: Thanks @M_Shimal. I added a sample dataset to illustrate what I mean. It is unclear to me if figure 1 was indeed drawn in R as it comes from another group's publication but it is an elegant way to represent that data, hence I was interested in reproducing it.

Answer (score 2):

I might recommend using a series of geoms, one for each sequence. If you have your data organized in a certain way, it would be fairly straightforward. For example, if your data is in long format as follows:

```
dat <- data.frame(sequence=c(1,2,2,2), start=c(1,1,2001,8000), stop=c(9000,2000,7999,9000), type=c("mapped","mapped","deletion","mapped"))
```

Which looks like...

```
sequence start stop     type
       1     1 9000   mapped
       2     1 2000   mapped
       2  2001 7999 deletion
       2  8000 9000   mapped
```

You could do the following:

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(data=dat, mapping=aes(ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=start, xmax=stop, fill=type)) +
geom_rect() + facet_grid(sequence~., switch="y") +
labs(x="Position (BP)", y="Sequence / Strain", title="Mapped regions for all sequences") +
theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Which looks like[image: this]

Comment: Thanks Cory. This is really helpful. The only issue is that the data is not organized as such. It only has the mapped regions. I edited my post above in case it is helpful.

Comment: You could run the same code as above with `xmin` and `xmax` as Mapped Start  and Mapped End  for your dataset though that will only plot mapped sections and will have the other parts empty. Would you need to show empty sections shown as deletion?

Comment: @M_Shimal I mapped it and have the deletions as blank. I think it looks quite good now actually. My final thought would be related to the order they are displayed. I tried a few things to alter the order of the sequences or manually dictate which sequences are drawn, but I haven't figured it out yet. Would appreciate your input. Many thanks!