# Plotting coordinates for sequence alignment 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I wanted to make a plot like the example mentioned in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416587/plotting-coordinates-for-sequence-alignment). My only issue is that the colors does not change and stick to standard. Does anyone know where the problem is?

My data frame is :

```r
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(
  sequence = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 22), 
  start = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 3000, 3500, 2300, 1500, 4000, 6000), 
  stop = c(8971, 8971, 8950, 8965, 8990, 8971, 9010, 8983, 8971, 8971, 9229, 9006, 8983, 8971, 8965, 8954, 9229, 8971, 9006, 8971, 8982, 5000, 8971), 
  type = c("Intact", "Intact", "Hypermute", "Hypermute", "Hypermute", "Hypermute", "Hypermute", "Defect", "Defect", "Defect", "Defect", "Defect", "Defect", "Defect", "Defect", "Defect", "Defect", "Defect", "Defect", "PSC", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion")
)
```

For plotting:

```r
ggplot(data=dat, mapping=aes(ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=start, xmax=stop,  fill = type)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(fill = type))  + 
  facet_grid(sequence~., switch="y") + 
  labs(x="Position (BP)", y="Sequence / Strain", title="Mapped regions for all sequences") + 
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red", "blue", "grey", "yellow")))
```

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis after `scale_fill_manual()` and lack one parenthesis after the second `theme()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem. It got solved.

Comment: teunbrand, consider making this an answer so you can get reputation for it.